# WebView's loadUrl method is not working when using ProGuard in Android (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, webview, proguard

we have a jar that contains a class that extends WebView, when importing this jar to the main project the signed (with ProGuard) apk does not load (with loadUrl WebView's method) the requested file.

Here is the ProGuard file:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepattributes JSInterface
-keep public class jar_package_name.WebviewClass$JSInterface
-keep public class * implements jar_package_name.WebviewClass$JSInterface 
-keepclassmembers class jar_package_name.WebviewClass$JSInterface { 
    <methods>; 
}
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface


-keepclassmembers class jar_package_name.WebviewClass {
   public *;
}
```

Thanks for the helpers.